# Closing an active app using ADB

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, shell, default-applications, wakelock

I need help closing an active connection in Android ADB on a rooted device. I tried everything that stackoverflow and Google can suggest for the past week. I even tried to uninstall the package. It worked for other active apps but not for this one. Any help will be appreciated.

`1 active connections Connection Number: 0 Operating Mode: NORMAL com.android.server.display.DisplayPowerController | WakeLockRefCount 0 | uid 1000 | cache size 0 | max cache size 0`

Comment: What app is it?

Answer (score 2):

## It's not changed in a while, you know.

In fact, since Honeycomb (Android 3.x) You can just run the following in adb:

```
adb shell am force-stop [PACKAGE]
```

Of course, replace [PACKAGE] with the package you want to chop up.

Comment: Force-stop is just one of the things I tired. I tired others which worked on other active apps. And I mentioned this in my original question.

Comment: @WsdmSkr Huh. try adb reboot then?

Comment: Reboot? That just restarts the device and the service is still active when I ran 'dumpsys sensorservice'. Is there any way I can kill this service?

Comment: Its unkillable then. Its to do with the screen, so no surprise really - just being hopeful. I'm just gonna ask one thing first: did you use adb root first??